# VLC media player sound problem

Tags: sound, vlc

When I skip forward or backward while playing movies the audio goes off while the video still plays. By this I mean that the audio stops playing while the video continues.

How do I solve it?

Comment: Do other video players exhibit the same problem? Also, I suppose you use PulseAudio as audio back-end for VLC Player.

Comment: The Default player for Ubuntu does not show this problem. Yes I use PulseAudio.

Comment: In that case, please supply the output of `pactl list sinks`, and `pactl list sink-inputs` (once with VLC playing a video with working sound, once after breaking sound through skipping).

Comment: Try to disable and then allow audio track in Audio -> Audio Track.

Comment: I preferences/audio I choosed "sortie audio ASA" (french fr Audio output ASA) and it was solved